# How to safely rename parent directory containing RoR apps?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, rename

I have various apps in a structure like so

```
C
--Sites
----App1
------.git
----App2
------.git
```

I wish to rename the `Sites` folder to `Apps_RoR`.
But there are various resulting path errors, not limited to git, GitBash, and maybe RoR itself.
What is the proper way to rename the folder containing your various RoR apps projects?

(`Sites` is the folder that loads immediately upon opening GitBash)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 git mv Sites Apps_RoR
```

If Sites is not a repository and just contains git projects, then do the following:

```
 mv Sites Apps_RoR
```

Please let me know if you have any questions!

Comment: Don't git commands work only for files within the folder the got folder is in? In my above example, git is in the project folder app1. That command would work for any file or folder in the app1 folder, but can it work for app1 itself? Does it work for the parent folder of app1?

Comment: I know that would work for files and folders within app1, but would it work for app1 itself? What about the parent folder of of app1? I'll try it once I get to my comp, but I thought I'd post some initial thoughts.

Comment: In my GitBash, when I type in the command you provided from the `Sites` folder, it says `fatal:L Not a git respository (or any of the parent directores): .git` (which is weird, because it is a parent directory of multiple git respositories.

Comment: When I do it within one of my apps, which is a git repository, I get `fatal: bad source, source=Sites, destination=Apps_RoR`

Comment: hey, if "Sites" is not a folder that's a repository, then you should be able to do a simple "mv Sites Apps_RoR". Git itself is indifferent to the name you give this directory and doesn't mind if you change it. could you please do this and let me know everything is OK? :-)

Comment: rails apps should be self-contained and not depended on their absolute path. i guess you have messed that up somewhere. solve it by using relative paths, or `Rails.root` etc.

Comment: agreed with @MarianTheisen, rails apps and git shouldn't care about the absolute path as long as the self contained files don't change

Comment: I'm in the parent folder of `Sites`. I do `mv Sites Apps_RoR` and all it tells me is `mv: cannot move Sites to Apps_RoR`

Comment: @MarianTheisen Can you give me a little more context to what you mean? I'm new to this. I'm not quite sure how to do that, or where to look. Do you mean my app may simply be using absolute route references? In that case, wouldn't the app simply break, rather than the terminal block me from renaming the folder?

Comment: My issue was that stuff wtihin those folders were still open. In short, the answer is "simply rename it."

however, there is an issue with GitBash. GitBash by default wants to load that `Sites` folder, and if it doesn't find it, it goes to some other folder. You have to somehow configure your gitbash to detect it, unless you don't mind navigating to the proper folder every time you open a gitbash terminal